# Visual Studio Coded UI test won't run - startup object empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

Created a recorded Coded UI test - it worked fine but won't run today.

Error: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project."

Googled and made sure this test is setup as startup project. However, when I go to the properties of the project, "Startup object" under Application tab is set to "(Not set)".

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "**Run**" or "**Debug**" commands from the context (right click) menu, or from the **Test Explorer** window or from the **Test** menu. The green **Start** button and the commands on the **Debug** menu do not start Coded UI tests. (They did start Coded UI In Visual Studio 2010.)

Comment: Wow! It did work as you said. Thank you so much! BTW, if I remember correctly, I was always using VS 2012. This is very strange.