# Need Visual Studio Toolbar Button To Start Coded UI Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, toolbar, coded-ui-tests

I want to add a button to my Visual Studio toolbar that will start debugging the Coded UI test that I have in the Visual Studio code window, and another button that will run the test I have there ("Run" and "Debug" options). I've been looking for this off and on for two years in VS2012, 2013, and 2015.

Does anyone know where to find these commands in the "Add/Remove Buttons => Customize => Toolbar => Add Command" dialog? Or maybe somewhere else along with how to implement them in a V.S. toolbar?

I have been customizing Visual Studio toolbars since VS2005. I like having buttons that do things quickly (e.g. in a single click). Of course, I know how to right-click and select Debug or Run to start a test. The Debug and Run commands are positioned *somewhere* on that shortcut menu (a poor name in this case, since it contains a minimum of 32 items and sometimes more than 40), but they move around depending on what else is in the menu. I would prefer to have just one place to find the command. You know: Point-n-click.

For anyone who isn't familiar with Coded User Interface Testing (Coded UI), you can't just set a startup project. A Coded UI project generates a DLL, not an exe, so neither F5 nor the green ">" will work in a Coded UI project.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499015/visual-studio-coded-ui-test-wont-run-startup-object-empty

Comment: This is not an answer, and in fact, it's on the context menu itself. You can use `Ctrl+R, T` to run the test that's in in the main code window. I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311501/) about how to make a keystroke into a toolbar button.