# How Do I Add A Keystroke To VS 2015 Toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've found a keystroke that I'd like to create as a button on my Visual Studio toolbar. If it matters, the keystroke is `Ctrl+r, Ctrl+t`.

This command is not listed in the "Add/Remove Buttons => Customize => Toolbar => Add Command" dialog.

Does anyone know how to add a toolbar button based on a keystroke?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a keystroke to the VS toolbar. So, first you have to find the command name in Visual Studio keyboard options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't help because I can't find the TestExpplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext in the list of commands (Tools=>Customize=>Commands=>Add Command) in any of the categories. Believe me, I've looked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394784/adding-a-visual-studio-toolbar-button-for-a-command-that-is-only-available-as-a