# Error when trying to run a codedUI test

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am getting this error despite setting the option "Set as startup project". My application is a web based (browser) application. I have tried all other options and it does not work. Please advise ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNDzU.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot debug a unit testing project in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594018/cannot-debug-a-unit-testing-project-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Coded UI test won't run - startup object empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499015/visual-studio-coded-ui-test-wont-run-startup-object-empty)

Comment: Has one of the suggested duplicates solved your problem? If yes then please accept that duplicate so the question can be closed. If not then please [edit] the question to further explain the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put 'CodedUI' and 'TestMethod' attributes in your test class and test methods, else you would get such error.

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
         BrowserWindow br = new BrowserWindow();
         BrowserWindow.Launch("www.Google.com");
    }
}
```